# Is memristance missing from our models?

Tags: resistors, memory, math

Since memristors are fundamental two-terminal, passive elements, is memristance a missing contributor that should now be included in distributed element calculations and parasitic extraction?

Comment: I am not an expert on that, but modelling things like RF in pcbs just needs good ol' maxwells equations.

Answer (score 4):

Unlikely.  For there to be a "parasitic" effect, there has to be some physical component of the circuit that, by its nature, is that parasitic effect's cause.  For a parasitic capacitance, all you need is two conductors separated by a dielectric, or in fact even a lone conductor (self-capacitance).  For a parasitic inductor, all one really needs is a length of conductor (self-inductance).  Obviously, these things occur naturally all over any physical circuit you would to construct, and outside the nice "lumped" elements one considers in circuit theory.

On the other hand, it seems that the memristor is a type of device, like a negative capacitor or a functionally dependent negative resistor, that doesn't naturally appear in circuits unless we go out of our way to construct one.  According to the Wikipedia page the idea of memristor wasn't even proposed until 1971, so that such a function even existed was relatively non-obvious, unlike the concepts of resistance, inductance, and capacitance, which were well known effects even in the early 1800s when electrical theory was still in its infancy.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, the parasitic effects start to become relevant for nanoscale devices.  From [HP's Memristor FAQ](http://www.hpl.hp.com/news/2008/apr-jun/memristor_faq.html):

> We were the first to understand that the hysteresis that was being
>   observed in the I-V curves of a wide variety of materials and
>   structures was actually the result of memristance and something more
>   general that can be called 'memristive behavior' [see L.O. Chua & S.
>   M. Kang, "Memristive devices and systems," Proc. IEEE 64, 209-223
>   (1976)] ... From this, we could for the first time write down a formula
>   for the memristance of a device in terms of material and geometrical
>   properties of the device (just as the resistance is the resistivity of
>   the material times the length divided by the cross sectional area of
>   the resistor). Our memristance formula immediately showed that the
>   size of the most important term in the memristance gets larger the
>   smaller the device – thus showing that it was not very important for
>   micron-scale electronics but is becoming very important for nanoscale
>   devices.